# ActiveRecord: StaleObjectError with different number of threads

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, optimistic-locking

ActiveRecord with optimistic locking. My program provokes `StaleObjectError`. When I run with 3 threads, I get dozens of such errors, as expected. However, when I run with 2 threads, I get exactly one such error, relatively at the beginning of execution. Any explanations?

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "number"
    t.string "lock_version"
  end
end
```

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

User.create

def write(x)
  begin
    user = User.find(1)
    sleep(SecureRandom.random_number)
    user["number"] = x
    user.save
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError => e
    puts "stale object error"
    retry
  end
end

def doit
  x = Thread.current.object_id
  100.times { write(x) }
end

t = []
ARGV[0].to_i.times { t = t + [ Thread.new { doit } ] }
t.each { |t| t.join }
```

- Running with argument 1, this prints nothing (as expected).
- Running with argument 2, this prints "stale object error" exactly once (not
  expected).
- Running with argument 3, this prints "stale object error" multiple times (as expected).